# How do I get Trello to re-send my confirmation email?

Tags: trello, notifications, email

I signed up, checked my spam filter, and cannot find the confirmation email anywhere. What do I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try resending the email via https://trello.com/resendValidate. If you still don't get an email after a few minutes (and you're sure it's not simply spam-filtered), contact support@trello.com .